# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ \ \ n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha + \beta=0$, find values of $\alpha,\beta$ and compute $8(\alpha+\beta)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ \ \ n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha + \beta=0$, find values of $\alpha,\beta$ and compute $$8(\alpha+\beta)$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha+\beta=0$$

And since $n \rightarrow \infty$, the $\frac{1}{n^t}, (t=1,2..)$ terms will get cancelled so:

$n+n\alpha=0$ should be 0 for the limit to be defined

$$\implies \alpha=-1$$

And since the entire limit is $0$, and only $\beta$ is left so:

$\beta=0$

$$8(\alpha+\beta)=-8$$

The answer given in my textbook is $-4$. Please help me out with the mistake.

Comment: Why are you immediately saying $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha=0$$when the problem said $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha+\beta=0?$$Where did $\beta$ go?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: Your mistake comes from the fact you’ve neglected the terms under the square root. Yes, $1/n^t$ will approach $0$ in the limit, but the $1/n$ term in particular will add a constant when scaled by $n$. I suggest you use the series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ with $x = -1/n - 1/n^2$, then solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that way.

Comment: "but the 1/n
 term in particular will add a constant when scaled by n" Can u elaborate more? I don't understand this

Comment: For $|x| \lt 1$, you have that $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \ ...$. This is the series expansion I mentioned. When you apply this to your case with $x = -1/n - 1/n^2$, you have that $$n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} = n \left(1 + \frac{(-1/n - 1/n^2)}{2} + \ ... \right)$$ $$= n - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n} + \ ...$$ Where the $1/2n$ term approaches zero as $n \to \infty$. So when you multiply the square root by $n$, you actually pick up a constant term of $-1/2$. This is why $\beta = -1/2$

Comment: Although $$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}$$ approaches $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity, $$n \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}$$ approaches $n - 1/2$.

Comment: Yes I understood this now. Could you convert this into an answer, so that i could accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: @LucaArmstrong While it is neat, I think usually series expansion comes later in the material. This question can be handled with manipulation during limit lessons which are usually very early materials, although I am not sure myself the background of this question.

Comment: Alright, well this is just one way you could approach the problem, but fair enough if series expansions are further on in the course.

Comment: @apocalyptic yes, I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $\sqrt{1+x}$ can be written as the following series expansion

$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \ ... \tag{1}$$

when $|x| < 1$.

Applying this to your limit with $x := - 1/n - 1/n^2, \ $ gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} + \alpha n + \beta \tag{2}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(1 + \frac{(-1/n - 1/n^2)}{2} - \ ...\right) + \alpha n + \beta \tag{3}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} n - \frac{1}{2} + \ ... \ + \alpha n + \beta. \tag{4}$$

For this limit to equal $0$, we need both the terms in $n$ and the constant terms to cancel.

Thus, it's clear that

$$\alpha = -1 \ \text{ and } \ \beta = \frac{1}{2} \tag{5}$$

Hence,

$$8(\alpha + \beta) = 8\left(-1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) = -4 \tag{6}$$

Keep in mind that when writing out the expansion in the limit, we neglected any terms of size $1/n^2$ or smaller, as they approach zero even when multiplied by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha + \beta &= \left(n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n\alpha + \beta\right)\frac{n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} -(n\alpha + \beta)}{n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} -(n\alpha + \beta)}\\
&=\frac{n^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) -(n^2\alpha^2 + 2n\alpha\beta+\beta^2)}{n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} -(n\alpha + \beta)}\\
&=\frac{n^2(1-\alpha^2)-n(1+2\alpha\beta)-(1+\beta^2)}{n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} -(n\alpha + \beta)}.\\
\end{align}

Hence, if we take the limit of the right-hand side, it would not exist, unless $1-\alpha^2= 0$. Hence, either $\alpha=-1$ or $1$. But if $\alpha$ is not negative, the left-hand side also would not exist. So, $\alpha=-1$. Thus, the right-hand side becomes

$$\frac{-n(1-2\beta)-(1+\beta^2)}{n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}} +n - \beta}.$$

Hence, the limit gives $\frac{2\beta-1}{2}=0$. Thus, $\beta=1/2$, and hence $8(\alpha+\beta)=-4$.

EDIT: To answer why yours is faulty, it's the part where you said $n+n\alpha$ must be zero for the limit to exist. What's right to say is only that $\alpha$ must be negative.

Comment: I know, this solution is given in my book too. I actually wanted to know why my method is giving a faulty answer. If you could edit and explain the same?

Comment: @apocalyptic When you say $n+\alpha n$ must be zero, that's incorrect.

Comment: but like i solved the term under the square root comes out to be 1, also since n tends to infinity, it makes sense to equate the sum of all coefficients to 0. I still don't see any fault in this

Comment: Yes, but you cannot conclude that because there are other possibilities. If it is for example $n-5n$, do you think the limit cannot exist?

Comment: To quote what you wrote: "$n+n\alpha$ must be $0$ for the limit to be defined". This is not true. It can be something nonzero, and the limit can still be defined. In this problem, what you want to avoid is the case where the limit is not defined, right? And that case is precisely when $\alpha\geq 0$, because in this case you will get $\infty+\infty$ which is $\infty$, meaning it does not exist. So, the correct phrase is: "$\alpha$ must be negative for the limit to be defined".